# Understand the use of braces and parenthesis in if

Tags: linux, shell, unix, if-statement

In some of the code I was going through I found that `if` was using **braces** `{}` for someplace and **parenthesis** `(())` for some other. Can someone tell me the exact meaning and where to use which one?

```
if [ "$1" = "--help" ]

if (( $# != 3 ))
```

Comment: Is there anything missing in the shell (bash) manual on Linux? Type `man bash` and in the pager, type `/\( \(`.

Answer (score 0):

The bracket `[` is a built-in command of the shell; you can also call it as `test`:

```
if [ a = b ]
then ...
```

equals:

```
if test a = b
then ...
```

The syntax of the `test` command is rather text-oriented (see the bash man page for details at chapter `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS`).

The braces `{…}` are shell syntax and used for grouping commands (without creating a subshell):

```
{ date; ls; echo $$; } > 1>&2
```

This will execute `date`, `ls`, and `echo $$` and redirect all their output to stderr.

The parenthesis `(…)` are shell-syntax and used for creating a subshell:

```
(date; ls; echo $$) > 1>&2
```

Like above but the PID (`$$`) given out is that of the subshell.

The difference between grouping and subshell is delicate (and out of scope here).

The doubled brackets `[[…]]` are shell syntax but otherwise behave like the single bracket `[` command.  The only difference is for using `<` etc. for string comparison and locale support.

The doubled parentheses `((…))` are equivalent to using the `let` builtin shell command.  They basically allow number-oriented expressions to be evaluated (`ARITHMETIC EVALUATION`).  `<` and `>` sort numerically (instead of lexicographically) etc.  Also, in some constructs like `for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do echo "$i"; done` they are used as a fixed syntax.

Dollar-parenthesis `$(…)` result in the *output* of the command they enclose:

```
echo "$(date)"  # a complicated way to execute date
```

Dollar-brackets `$[…]` are deprecated and should be replaced by dollar-double-parentheses.

Dollar-double-parentheses `$((…))` result in the value of the numerical expression they enclose:

```
echo "$((4 + 3 * 2))"  # should print 10
```

Dollar-braces `${…}` result in the variable expansion they enclose.  In the simplest case this is just a variable name, then they evaluate to the variable value:

```
a=foo
echo "${a}"  # prints foo
```

This can (and often is) abbreviated by stripping the braces:  `$a`

But it also can be more complex like `${a:-"today is $(date)"}`.  See `Parameter Expansion` in the bash man page for details.

Redirection-parenthesis `<(…)` and `>(…)` create a subprocess, a file descriptor its output/input is associated with, and a pseudo file associated with that descriptor.  It can be used to pass the output of a program as a seeming file to another program:  `diff <(sleep 1; date) <(sleep 2; date)`